# Node.js - save xlsx to disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, excel-2007, js-xlsx

I am using Node.js and [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) for generating new Excel files.
When a new file is generated I want it to be saved to local disk.

This code is used generating and downloading a new Excel file, how can it be stored to disk instead?

```
FileManagement.generateExcelFile("xlsx-filtered-list", "error-sheet", finalResult, res);

generateExcelFile(fileName, sheetName, data, res) {
    const workSheet = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data);
    const workBook = new Workbook();

    workBook.SheetNames.push(sheetName);
    workBook.Sheets[sheetName] = workSheet;

    const workBookOptions = { bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:false, type:'binary' };
    const workBookFile = xlsx.write(workBook, workBookOptions);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+fileName);
    res.end(workBookFile, 'binary');

    // Functions work Excel generation (don't touch)
    function Workbook() {
        if(!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
        this.SheetNames = [];
        this.Sheets = {};
    }

    function sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data) {
        const workSheet = {};
        const range = {s: {c:10000000, r:10000000}, e: {c:0, r:0 }};
        for(let R = 0; R != data.length; ++R) {
            for(let C = 0; C != data[R].length; ++C) {
                if(range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
                if(range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
                if(range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
                if(range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;
                const cell = {v: data[R][C] };
                if(cell.v == null) continue;
                const cell_ref = xlsx.utils.encode_cell({c:C,r:R});

                if(typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
                else if(typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
                else if(cell.v instanceof Date) {
                    cell.t = 'n'; cell.z = xlsx.SSF._table[14];
                    cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
                }
                else cell.t = 's';

                workSheet[cell_ref] = cell;
            }
        }
        if(range.s.c < 10000000) workSheet['!ref'] = xlsx.utils.encode_range(range);

        return workSheet;
    }
}
```

Comment: const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('./public/uploaded-files/hello.xlsx', FileManagement.generateExcelFile("error-list.xlsx", "error-sheet", filteredData[1], res));

This code writes the file to disk, but it isn't usable due to file format extension error.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution:

```
/* output format determined by filename */
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'out.xlsx');
/* at this point, out.xlsx is a file that you can distribute */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following method:

```
var FileSaver = require('file-saver')

/* add worksheet to workbook */
wb.SheetNames[0] = 'Testing';
wb.Sheets['Testing'] = ws;  //worksheet handle

var wopts = { bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:false, type:'binary'};
var wbout = XLSX.write(wb,wopts);

/* the saveAs call downloads a file on the local machine */
FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type: ""}), "test.xlsx")
```